# Software to encrypt videos to a format viewable in browsers on Mac, Windows 10, iOS 12, and Android

Tags: gratis, video, web-development, encryption, drm

Using a PHP library that relies on ffmpeg, I was able to [encrypt a bunch of videos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60852109/470749) (mostly mp4 but not all) to HLS m3u8 playlists of encrypted fragments. Using https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js, my website is able to play those videos in most browsers but not on iOS 12.

https://caniuse.com/#search=hls says that iOS 13.2+ is required for HLS videos, but I need to be able to support phones as old as iPhone 6, which can only run iOS 12 and lower.

I'd be shocked if there isn't a way to do what I'm looking to do:

When I start over, what should I use to encrypt videos to a format (which format?) that is viewable in browsers on Mac, Windows 10, iOS 12, and Android (using which client-side libraries, if required)?

P.S. @Izzy Thanks for the questions. A PHP library would be ideal, but PHP can also call other programs as long as they're executable in Ubuntu (Linux). Yes, free ($0). By "encrypt", I mean that (like HLS) there is a key/password that the system uses when encrypting the videos, and then the browser/client has also knows that key and uses it for decryption. For quality, resolution, etc, I want as close to lossless as possible. I don't see why encryption would require any loss (hopefully not). Maybe someone here knows of an HLS alternative that suits my needs (would DASH?).

Answer (score 1):

Alas there's no one media format(*) that can address "browsers on Mac, Windows 10, iOS 12, and Android" simultaneously. Your best bet is to encode in two formats: HLS (for the legacy Apple side of things) and MPEG-DASH (for the rest of the world).

There are some commercial tools, such as [Unified Streaming](https://www.unified-streaming.com/) or [Wowza](https://www.wowza.com/) which will let you encode once to a "mezzanine file" (basically a set of MP4 files, one per bitrate) and then allow you to convert them *on the fly* to the format the requesting device is capable of handling, including DRM.

Otherwise, you can roll your own multi-format streams using tools like the open-source [Shaka Packager](https://github.com/google/shaka-packager), which will let you manually encode & encrypt to both MPEG-DASH (+Widevine DRM) and HLS (+FairPlay DRM).

(*) Technically, there is one nowadays -- CMAF. [This article](https://www.unified-streaming.com/blog/new-http-live-streaming-hls-common-media-application-format) is a good primer on it, but player support for CMAF is still patchy at best.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for effort. Unfortunately iOS 12 does not support HLS or probably any of those other approaches. I’m shocked at how complicated or impossible what I thought such a simple project is.